# Node JS TCP Server with simple password prompt problem

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to build a TCP server on node JS. The idea is to have multiple TCP clients connect and send / receive data(from server to client / client to server) and to have some sort of authentication (at least to enter a strong password) Also not sure if this approach is worth it. But, I've come up with something (most from online sources and docs) and crated below code.

Code runs and I can connect, but if I send data from client to server, the "password" check function fires up and each time I enter the correct password, a new (duplicate connection) is created. Seems like it keeps calling the same function on each input.
Desired behavior would be ; once client try's to connect, needs to provide the password and then start sending date. Also could someone give me a hint on how to send data back from server, or is it even possible. Or do I need to create a separate function for server.createConnection()

thanks in advance
UPDATE :I've changed the code a bit, but the main issue remains. this bit was supposed to check whether "`clientAddress`" exists and if so skip the auth part all together.

```
server.on('connection', (socket) => {

    let clientAddress = `${socket.remoteAddress}:${socket.remotePort}`;

    console.log(clientAddress)
    if(sock.indexOf(clientAddress) !== -1){
        console.log('devie found, opening communication')

        newConnectionHandler(socket,clientAddress)

    } else {
        console.log('devie not found, need to authenticate')

        userAuth(socket,clientAddress)
    }
```

but as you can guess, it's not working :) if I manually specify the "`clientAddress`" it works , if I place "`sock.push(clientAddress);`" within the first block of code, it also works. No auth is asked. But when it's placed within

```
function userAuth(socket,clientAddress){
    socket.write('password : ' )
        socket.on('data', function (data) {
           let pass = data.toString()

            if (pass == password) {
                sock.push(clientAddress);
                console.log(sock)
                newConnectionHandler(socket,clientAddress)
                return;
            } else {
                //console.log(pass)
                socket.write('Sorry, you cannot access the server \n')

                console.log('acess denied for ' + socket.remoteAddress + ':' + socket.remotePort + '\n')
                socket.write('connection closed')
                socket.destroy()
            }

        }) 

}
```

code does run as expected and goes all the way till

```
function newConnectionHandler(socket,clientAddress){

    //console.log(sock)
    socket.write('Welcome \n')

    socket.on('data', function(data1){
      console.log("Client Sent: " + data1);

    });
```

but as soon as I send a new message from the client, it goes back as if it was never authenticated and treats my input as the password and because it does not match with the actual password,it destroys the connection.

can someone please give me a hand...

```
const net = require('net'); 
const port = 3001; 
const host = '192.168.0.165'; 
const server = net.createServer()

let sock = [];
let password = 123

//server.on('listening',createConnection);
server.on('connection', (socket) => {
    
    let clientAddress = `${socket.remoteAddress}:${socket.remotePort}`;
    
    console.log(clientAddress)
    if(sock.indexOf(clientAddress) !== -1){
        console.log('devie found, opening communication')
     
        newConnectionHandler(socket,clientAddress)
        
    } else {
        console.log('devie not found, need to authenticate')
 
        userAuth(socket,clientAddress)
    }


server.on('error', errorHandler);

function errorHandler(err){
    console.log(`Error occurred in ${clientAddress}: ${err.message}`);
}

function userAuth(socket,clientAddress){
    socket.write('password : ' )
        socket.on('data', function (data) {
           let pass = data.toString()
           
            if (pass == password) {
                sock.push(clientAddress);
                console.log(sock)
                newConnectionHandler(socket,clientAddress)
                return;
            } else {
                //console.log(pass)
                socket.write('Sorry, you cannot access the server \n')
    
                console.log('acess denied for ' + socket.remoteAddress + ':' + socket.remotePort + '\n')
                socket.write('connection closed')
                socket.destroy()
            }
            
        }) 
    
}

function newConnectionHandler(socket,clientAddress){
    
    //console.log(sock)
    socket.write('Welcome \n')
   
    socket.on('data', function(data1){
      console.log("Client Sent: " + data1);

    });
    socket.once('close', (data) => { 
        let index = sock.findIndex((o) => { 
        return o.remoteAddress === socket.remoteAddress && o.remotePort === socket.remotePort; 
                }) 
        if (index !== -1) sock.splice(index, 1); 
        sock.forEach((sock) => { 
        socket.write(`${clientAddress} disconnected\n`); 
                }); 
        console.log(`connection closed: ${clientAddress}`); 
            }); 
    }

 /*  function createConnection(){
    // Start a connection to the server
    var socket = server.on('connect',function(){
      // Send the initial message once connected
      socket.write({question: "Hello, world?"});
    });
    
    // Whenever the server sends us an object...
    socket.on('data', function(data){
      // Output the answer property of the server's message to the console
      console.log("Server's answer: " + data.answer);
      
    
    });
  } */

})

server.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log('TCP Server is running on port ' + port + '.');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it appears as the only bit of code that was causing the authentication loop was the

```
function userAuth(socket,clientAddress){
    socket.write('password : ' )
        **socket.on('data', function (data) {**
           let pass = data.toString()
```

after changing "on" with "once" it is now functioning properly. I tested with two TCP clients, both connected and was asked to enter a password. They can both actively send messages to the server and both disconnected properly in the end.

this is the code if anyone finds any use for it :) the connection it's self is still unencrypted so not good for sending/receiving sensitive data.

```
const net = require('net'); 
const port = 3001; 
const host = '192.168.0.165'; 
const server = net.createServer()

let sock = [];
let password = 123

//server.on('listening',createConnection);
server.on('connection', (socket) => {
    
    let clientAddress = `${socket.remoteAddress}:${socket.remotePort}`;
    
    console.log(clientAddress)
    if(sock.indexOf(clientAddress) !== -1){
        console.log('devie found, opening communication')
     
        newConnectionHandler(socket,clientAddress)
        
    } else {
        console.log('devie not found, need to authenticate')
 
        userAuth(socket,clientAddress)
    }

})
server.on('error', errorHandler);

function errorHandler(err){
    console.log(`Error occurred in ${clientAddress}: ${err.message}`);
}

function userAuth(socket,clientAddress){
    socket.write('password : ' )
        socket.once('data', function (data) {
           let pass = data.toString()
           
            if (pass == password) {
                sock.push(clientAddress);
                console.log(sock)
                newConnectionHandler(socket,clientAddress)
                return;
            } else {
                //console.log(pass)
                socket.write('Sorry, you cannot access the server \n')
    
                console.log('acess denied for ' + socket.remoteAddress + ':' + socket.remotePort + '\n')
                socket.write('connection closed')
                socket.destroy()
            }
            
        }) 
    
}

function newConnectionHandler(socket,clientAddress){
    
    //console.log(sock)
    socket.write('Welcome \n')
   
    socket.on('data', function(data1){
      console.log("Client Sent: " + data1);

    });

    socket.on('close', function(data) {
        let index = sock.findIndex(function(o) {
            return o.remoteAddress === sock.remoteAddress && o.remotePort === sock.remotePort;
        })
        if (index !== -1) sock.splice(index, 1);
        console.log('CLOSED: ' + socket.remoteAddress + ' ' + socket.remotePort);
    });

    }

 /*  function createConnection(){
    // Start a connection to the server
    var socket = server.on('connect',function(){
      // Send the initial message once connected
      socket.write({question: "Hello, world?"});
    });
    
    // Whenever the server sends us an object...
    socket.on('data', function(data){
      // Output the answer property of the server's message to the console
      console.log("Server's answer: " + data.answer);
      
    
    });
  } */



server.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log('TCP Server is running on port ' + port + '.');
});
```